# stochastic process with random variable as time, measurable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

i have a problem with the following exercise:
Let $X$ be an measurable $\mathbb{R}^d$ valued stochastic process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $T$ a finite $T : \Omega\to \big[ 0, +\infty \big)$ random time. 
. Show that $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

I know how to show $\{\omega\in \Omega|{X_{T(\omega)}(\omega)}\in B\} \in  \mathcal{F}$, but only if T would take values in $\mathbb{N}$.
I have no clue how to show it for a real valued random time.

thank you

edit:Yes $X$ is measurable on the space $(\Omega \times [ 0, +\infty),\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$

Comment: Does measurable mean that the mapping $(\omega,t)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{B}([0,\infty))$ on $\Omega\times [0,\infty)$?

Comment: I added the information to the Question. yes measurable was ment like you wrote

Comment: My answer here may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190220/the-strong-markov-property-with-an-uncountable-index-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Bryon Schmuland, the answer of "[The strong Markov property with an uncountable index set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190220/the-strong-markov-property-with-an-uncountable-index-set)" does answer my question too.
I was first put off why $T$ should be finite, but since then $\{T<\infty \}=\Omega, X_T$ is well defined for every $\omega$ without having to look at the Limits.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about why T should be finite?